# Erroneous Statement from Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, fake-proofs

**"Theorem":** Consider two spaces $W$ and $U$ of finite dimension. If $W \subset U$ then $W^*=U^*$.

**Proof:**

1. $W^\ast$ is a subset of $U^\ast$:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   W &= \langle e_1, \ldots, e_k \rangle, \\
   U& = \langle e_1, \ldots, e_k, \ldots, e_n \rangle, 
   \end{align*}$$
   then
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   W^\ast &= \langle e^\ast_1, \ldots, e^\ast_k \rangle,
   \\
   U^\ast &= \langle e^\ast_1, \ldots, e^\ast_k, \ldots, e^\ast_n \rangle.
   \end{align*}$$
   It's clear to see that $W^* \subset U^*$.
2. $U^\ast$ is a subset of $W^\ast$:

Any functional $U^\ast \ni f: U \to \bf R$ is also functional over $W$, so $U^\ast \subset W^\ast$.

More exactly:
$$ f(U) \subset {\bf R} \Rightarrow f (W \subset U) \subset {\bf R}.$$

So $W^\ast = U^\ast$.

Where is mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both directions contain conceptual errors. First, taking dual spaces is a little more complicated than putting stars on everything. It's true that if $W$ is a subspace of $U$ then $\dim W \le \dim U$, hence $\dim W^{\ast} \le \dim U^{\ast}$, but one cannot extract from this a natural embedding of $W^{\ast}$ into $U^{\ast}$ which is independent of a choice of basis.

It is true that any linear functional in $U^{\ast}$ defines a linear functional in $W^{\ast}$ by restriction, but the corresponding map $U^{\ast} \to W^{\ast}$ is *not* injective, as you erroneously assume in the second direction. It *is* surjective: in other words, $W^{\ast}$ is naturally regarded as a *quotient*, not a subspace, of $U^{\ast}$.

Returning to the first direction, you can label a basis of $W^{\ast}$ by $e_1^{\ast}, ... e_k^{\ast}$ and a basis of $U^{\ast}$ by $e_1^{\ast}, ... e_n^{\ast}$, but if you start thinking of these in terms of the actual functions they describe, the natural thing to do is not to inject the first vector space into the second but to quotient the second by the span of $e_{k+1}^{\ast},  ... e_n^{\ast}$ (all of which act by zero on $W$) to get the first, which is what happens abstractly above.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't see what is meant by the first error? I interpret $<e_i >$ as the span of $\{e_i \}$, in which case the argument seems fine(modulo showing that there is a choice of basis such that $W=<e_1, \ldots , e_k>$ and $U=<e_1,\ldots , e_n>$). In which case, what's the complication?
EDIT: To fix grammar.

Comment: @Nick: the complication is that the embedding of $W^{\ast}$ into $U^{\ast}$ that the OP wants to describe is not natural, in the sense that it depends on a choice of basis. If all the OP wanted to prove is that $\dim W^{\ast} \le \dim U^{\ast}$, this would be fine, but the OP specifically says "subset" and this to me indicates a hidden naturality assumption (especially in that the OP seems to be implicitly identifying the functional $e_i^{\ast}$ on $W$ with the corresponding functional $e_i^{\ast}$ on $U$ as if they were literally the same object).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I read your statement as saying something like $W^{*}$ does not consist of the span of $\{e_1^{*}, \ldots , e_k^{*}\}$ which is obviously wrong. Thanks for clarifying.